# How to refresh networks and bluetooth in status menu (18.04)

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, indicator

On Ubuntu 18.04, the status menu (not sure of the name) on the top right does not refresh my network interfaces anymore, nor my bluetooth connections.
On the attached image, there are:

- (1) 2 network interfaces whereas there should be only one, and their content is wrong
- (2) 2 bluethooth connections whereas there shouldn't be any (I remove them)

On Ubuntu 16.04 I restarted `nm-applet` but this one is gone.
I tried `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` but no luck either.
Restarting does the trick but that's really not convenient...

Do you know any way to refresh this awesome status indicator which seems to always have a new way of breaking since I use Ubuntu? Thanks!

[image: status menu]

Comment: Profanity is not appreciated here, please remove from your question.

Comment: Does `sudo service network-manager restart` work?

Comment: it's not working either, but is it not the same than `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`.